# How to extract the union type of all objects in a constant array that extend a query type?

Tags: typescript

I have a constant array with objects that satisfy a type:

```
const X = [
 {a: 1, b: 2},
 {a: 3, b: 2},
 {a: 5, b: 4}
] as const satisfies {a: any};
```

Is there a way to get the union type of all the elements that extend a generic type that I pass. For example:

```
type b2 = Discriminator<X, {b: 2}>; // {a: 1, b: 2} | {a: 3, b: 2}
type b4 = Discriminator<X, {b: 4}>; // {a: 5, b: 4}
```

Comment: the built-in `Extract` is what you want, e.g. `type b2 = Extract<typeof X[number], { b: 2 }>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type Discriminator<T extends readonly unknown[], U> = Extract<T[number], U>
```

Here `Discriminator` is a type that accepts the array of objects as `T` and something to match against as `U`.

`T[number]` gets all possible array member types as a union, and then `Extract<T[number], U>` gets only the members of that union that match `U`

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAGjAvDA2gKBgbwIYC4YCMANDAEb4BMAvkRjvgMwnkzW1Z4wCsz+ALFTQBdGNggxQkKGjRQAngAcApjAAiASwjAATuoC26sNightAHgAqMJQA8oSsABNx2pdkfgANnJgBXMADWYCAA7mAoQiQAqgB8SDAAonba2MBQlihgvnqkStqRMLEy8spkFPEaWroGRibmJUogAGbwJJgs1DEA3DAA9L0c+MRklFQwAD6DMEwjrIL9MIsAegD8QA)

Comment: That wasn't working for me because of probably a TS compiler bug due to the complexity of the actual use case, but this reassurance that it should work helped me figure that out :)